# MySQL special characters problems

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have an issue with my mySQL queries and insertions.

When members write in the text area these characters, like:

```
' " < >
```

and some others..
the mySQL will give a database error.

What I can do to avoid this?
I think it is a usualthing in PHP.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the data before you try to insert it.

This will also protect you from [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your input before inserting it into your database.

See `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Hie Diego,

you can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape these characters.
Maybe htmlentites ist interesting for you, too ([htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php))

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix, escaping any string that goes into the app with mysql_real_escape_string will help.

For a better (and faster even!) solution, use `mysqli` and prepared statements - see e.g. this for a tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the addslashes() of php.

Comment: Addslashes is known for being insufficient (and has been for *years*). See e.g. this for an SQL injection despite addslashes(): http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string